# I want to put hover on background and text color at a time

Tags: html, css, background, hover

I need to put hover at a time on background and text color.. please tell me how could i do this...When i hover, i want to change the text color and background .. which property should i apply

here is my code and image.

http://s29.postimg.org/i0ivezr07/image.jpg

```css
.menu{
 height:65px;
 width:100%;
 background-color:#cccc99;
 box-shadow:0px 1px 2px #000000;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #000000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #000000;
}
.logo{
 float:left;
 margin: 5px 6px;
 position:relative;
}
.menu-text{
 float:right;
 width:570px;
 margin: -8px 0px;
}
.menu-text ul{
 list-style:none;
}
.menu-text ul li{
 float:left;
 height:60px;
 width:94px;
 line-height: 60px;
 border-right:1px solid #e6e6e6;
 text-align: center;
 font-size:16px;
 font-weight:bold;
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #757575;
}
.menu-text ul li:hover{

}
.menu-text ul li:last-child{
 border:none;
}
.menu-text ul li a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color: #333333;
}
.menu-text ul li a:hover{

}
.menu-text ul li a:hover ul li:hover{
 background-color:#FFF;
 color:#FFF;
 }
.menu-belt{
 width:100%;
 height:10px;
 background:#cccc99;
 box-shadow:0px -1px 2px #a9a9a9;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -1px 2px #a9a9a9;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px -1px 2px #a9a9a9;
 float:left;
 margin: -13px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<div class="logo">
<a href="#">
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
</a>
</div> <!--/logo-->
<div class="menu-text">
<ul>
   <li><a href="#"> Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"> Operator</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"> Drive </a></li>
   <li><a href="#"> Booking </a></li>
   <li><a href="#"> Rider </a></li>
   <li><a href="#"> Logout </a></li>
</ul>
</div> <!--/menu-text-->
<div class="menu-belt">
</div> <!--menu-belt-->
</div> <!--/menu-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add it on the :hover

```
.menu-text ul li a:hover{
    color: red;
    background-color: green;
}
```

:hover is the css used when the mouse if hovering on the element.

Comment: i have used this ... but it hover's when.. when our courser is on text.. not on li tag

Comment: @HafizZubairZahid then to the changes on the hover of li. .menu-text ul li:hover

Comment: i need both hover at a time. :(... still fail to apply.

Answer (score 0):

Use :hover property for CSS

Syntax:

classname:hover{ property1:value; property2:value;)

```css
.menu{
 height:65px;
 width:100%;
 background-color:#cccc99;
 box-shadow:0px 1px 2px #000000;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #000000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #000000;
}


.item1
{
  display:block;
  border:1px solid #000;
  width:60px;
  padding:10px;
}

.item1:hover
{
  
  background:lightgreen;
  color:white;
  }
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <span class="item1">MENU</span>
  </div>
```

CSS Syntax
classname:hover { color:green; background:red;}

Answer (score 0):

You also have to make the a-tag fill out the whole surrounding li element by adding display:block;

```css
.menu{
 height:65px;
 width:100%;
 background-color:#cccc99;
 box-shadow:0px 1px 2px #000000;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #000000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #000000;
}
.logo{
 float:left;
 margin: 5px 6px;
 position:relative;
}
.menu-text{
 float:right;
 width:570px;
 margin: -8px 0px;
}
.menu-text ul{
 list-style:none;
}
.menu-text ul li{
 float:left;
 height:60px;
 width:94px;
 line-height: 60px;
 border-right:1px solid #e6e6e6;
 text-align: center;
 font-size:16px;
 font-weight:bold;
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #757575;
}
.menu-text ul li:hover{

}
.menu-text ul li:last-child{
 border:none;
}
.menu-text ul li a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color: #333333;
    display: block; //this makes the a tag fill out the whole surrounding li
}
.menu-text ul li a:hover{
    background-color: red; //add this of course....
    color: green;
}
.menu-text ul li a:hover ul li:hover{
 background-color:#FFF;
 color:#FFF;
 }
.menu-belt{
 width:100%;
 height:10px;
 background:#cccc99;
 box-shadow:0px -1px 2px #a9a9a9;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -1px 2px #a9a9a9;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px -1px 2px #a9a9a9;
 float:left;
 margin: -13px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<div class="logo">
<a href="#">
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
</a>
</div> <!--/logo-->
<div class="menu-text">
<ul>
   <li><a href="#"> Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"> Operator</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"> Drive </a></li>
   <li><a href="#"> Booking </a></li>
   <li><a href="#"> Rider </a></li>
   <li><a href="#"> Logout </a></li>
</ul>
</div> <!--/menu-text-->
<div class="menu-belt">
</div> <!--menu-belt-->
</div> <!--/menu-->
```